# Using a WHERE EXISTS statement for two contradictory conditions in Redshift/Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm looking to write a query that, given an id, first name, and last name, returns IDs corresponding to every ID that has at least one row containing a first name 'Steve' and a last name 'Smith', in addition to at least one row that corresponds to a first name 'Steve' and does *not* correspond to a last name 'Smith'.  I tried the below query but it returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE first_name = 'Steve' AND last_name != 'Smith')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE first_name = 'Steve' AND last_name = 'Smith')
```

I suspect it's because *within a single row*, both conditions cannot simultaneously be true, even though they can both be true across multiple rows for the same ID.

How should I modify or rewrite this query to return the IDs of interest?

Comment: It sounds like you wanted two `exists` but you used `not exists` instead. But you probably also need to correlate your subqueries.

Comment: In your case, both the subqueries are uncorrelated. (they are not *coupled* to the outer query)

Comment: What do you mean by "uncorrelated?"

Comment: You inner queries should probably say `from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.first_name = 'Steve' ...` You're tying the two together otherwise those queries are running across the entire table of data.

Comment: They have no logical relation to the outer query; just like in `select id from a where exists (select 1 from b where b.name = 'omg' );` BTW: in your case both the EXISTS() and NOT EXISTS() can be true, because they select different sets from the same table)

Comment: Maybe `from t as t2`. Some platforms don't allow `as`; other probably require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you could write this another way. Give me all IDs where there's at least one Steve Smith but not all of them are Steve Smiths.

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(case when first_name = 'Steve' and last_name = 'Smith' then 1 end)
    between 1 and count(last_name) - 1
```